# Chrome Dev Tools Device Emulation strange cropping

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Hi all having an issue with Chrome Dev Tools device emulation where when I set a device the screen image is cropped to about a third of its correct size leaving the rest of the image with just a pale pink background. See attached. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image: Odd cropping of screen where top left corner is shown and the rest of the image is cropped showing only a pale pink background. This behaviour occurs using any device setting]

Answer (score 4):

This bug occurs for me when I open Chrome DevTools and activate the device emulator. Toggling the emulator off and then on again doesn't fix it.

The **workaround** I've found is to *close and re-open Chrome DevTools with the emulator still enabled*. By keyboard, that's hitting <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> twice.

Hopefully the bug will be addressed soon, given [its filing earlier today](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=821010) and [their positive response on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/973201533595774976).

- Chrome 65.0.3325.146
- macOS 10.13.3

Comment: Updated to 65.0.3325.162 today, haven't seen the bug since.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug.

I'll link this question to the existing bug report: https://crbug.com/821010

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. The only fix that worked was to un-dock the devtools window, as it was blocking the bottom of the device display, and i wasn't able to scroll to the bottom of the display. I only see this bug when using the device emulator, for all types of devices.